# Azure AD scim2 provisioning mapping primary email

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, provisioning, scim, scim2

We are trying to integrate our scim2 api with Azure AD and trying to figure out how to map the primary email value. We see that you can map multivalued attributes as in this document:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/app-provisioning/customize-application-attributes

But how does one map one of those values of a multi-valued attribute as being primary?

Regards,
LT

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately today Azure AD Provisioning doesn't allow for mapping of the primary value for email attributes. Right now, we allow customers to set email with type “work”, “home” and “other”. We default to work email as the “primary” if available.

Comment: Please let us know if this answer was helpful to you. If so, please remember to mark it as the answer using the check mark so that others in the community with similar questions can more easily find a solution. Also, Please spare few mins to let us know how we did using this link <https://microsoft.qualtrics.com/jfe/form/SV_6Sh1E5ZBWke4wO9?Q_DL=Fa5t8dkcKtAi0la_6Sh1E5ZBWke4wO9_MLRP_42PnMLMnFSZmORT&Q_CHL=gl
>